# Compose performance issue during navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, koin

Hello there guys  We've decided to rewrite our app to compose. However we've faced a performance issue, specially on slower devices (like my Xiaomi POCO X3). On Samsung S22 and on any emulator everything works fine.
So whats the problem? When I navigate from Screen A to Screen B (no matter if I am using navigation with Fragments, Voyager Appyx or anything) and during the navigation animation I change the state of Screen B (Loading -> Success/Error) I experience frame drop. I'm using MVI Architecture with the help of Orbit MVI library. I tried to optimize the compose with kotlinx ImmutableList library. The state of request is represented by sealed class model that contains: Uninitialised, Loading, Success or error. Everything marked with Immutable annotation. For DI I'm using Koin and thats probably the only thing I haven't changed yet to test it. Anyone had similar issues?

Comment: are you running a release build? or just a debug?

Comment: Yes, im running it on release build

Comment: If you are testing your app in debug mode this might be the issue. but if you test your release apk there will be no performance issue. and if issue still persist it might be your coding issue.

Comment: On a side note, have you tried baseline profiles? Compose might sometimes be less performant to XML based UI due to the JIT compilation which happens for your Kotlin bytecode. Instrumenting major scenarios like app boot and navigation of important screens can make a huge difference.

Comment: Ok i found what is causing the issue, but still don't know why. So... I was invoking the navigation from Screen A to Screen B by clicking on card inside lazy column. 
So i changed the method i navigate. After entering sceen A, in LaunchedEffect i've waited for 5 seconds, and then automatically i invoked the navigation. Aaaand... no lag.

After futher investigation i found out that the ripple effect on card click was causing the issue. When i removed it - everything works fine. But still... I don't know why is that. Why ripple effect is so heavy that it causing lags?